# Can a dweller have 10 points in each of the SPECIAL attributes?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Can a dweller have 10 points in each of the SPECIAL attributes? Or is there a limit to the points a dweller can have?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each dweller may have have each special stat at 10 points. I am currently training a large number of such dwellers for wasteland duty (so far I have only got one lvl 50 dweller with full special stats).